# Question vote count out of alignment

Tags: bug, design, asking-questions, related-questions

When entering a question title there is a list of "Questions that may already have your answer" appears. It shows the amount of votes beside the question, but if the question has more than 10 negative votes then a class `large` gets added which causes extra padding at the top and less padding at the bottom.

[image]

Removing that class fixes the extra padding at the top and less padding at the bottom.

```
.answer-votes.large 
{
    /* font-size: 90%; */
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```